# React JS cannot input text with non capital

Tags: reactjs

I have this problem that form cannot input text withouth capital at the first character even though I set the autoCapitalize to 'none' or even without the use autoCapitalize.

```
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          autoCapitalize='none'
        />
```

or

```
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
        />
```

I got the same problem with both of them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Mc5.png)

I forgot to mention this before. I tried using the basic module of reactJS to test it without anything added to it except the form but I still got the same problem. I never faced something like this before.

If someone knows how to fix this problem, please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO, start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Is it really not taking the input? If you are able to type in, that's what is expected from an input field. I'd suggest to check some event action like onSubmit where you can process the text input on the field.

Comment: Probably some other file controls it somewhere. Your snippet code should be fine. As we don't have an access to the rest of the code, I'd suggest you to look for a place in the project controlling this "autoCapitalize" attribute

Comment: You might have a css rule to capitalize the textbox.